# The only compact subgroups $G$ of the multiplicative complex numbers $\Bbb C^{\times}$ are the unit circle $S^{1}$ and the $n$th roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-numbers

I am new to abstract algebra and also topology and I struggling to understand this problem. What is the group of the multiplicative complex numbers? What does compact mean here? Why is the unit circle a compact subgroup of this group? Or the nth roots of unity. I will come up with the proof - but I wanted some direction on how to proceed.

Comment: $\mathbb C^\times$ denotes the group of non-zero complex numbers with multiplication

Comment: Thankyou @J.W.Tanner. Another auxiliary question -what does it mean when we say noncompact subgroup of $S^{1}$ the unit circle?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb C^{\times}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb C$, so it gets a subspace topology which in turn may be inherited by subsets of $\Bbb C^{\times}$, be they subgroups or not. The circle is compact because it is closed and bounded, and the set of $n$th roots of unity is compact because it is finite.

Comment: @IvoTerek - if every circle is compact, then can there be any noncopact subgroup of $S^{1}$ at all?

Comment: If you take the subgroup of the circle group generated by a rotation that’s not a rational fraction of $2\pi$, then you’ll get a dense subgroup of the circle group. For instance, you can take $\frac{2+i}{2-i}=\frac35+\frac45i$. This subgroup is certainly not compact.

Comment: Read your problem again: it asks about subgroups of $\Bbb C^\times$, not of $\Bbb S^1$. And there are non-compact subgroups of $\Bbb S^1$, such as $\{  {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i} n\alpha} \mid n \in \Bbb Z \}$ for $\alpha$ irrational (in fact, this is a proper and dense subgroup of $\Bbb S^1$).

Comment: @Lubin why is this not compact? by this I mean $3/5+4/5i$?

Comment: The subgroup generated by $\frac35+\frac45i$ is infinite cyclic, contained in the circle group. So it’s dense there but not the whole circle group at all.

Comment: I dint understand @Lubin since I dont know algebra. What do you mean by infinite cyclic?  It is a point in the plane. It is contained in  the group. Why do you call it dense?

Comment: I said *the subgroup generated by* that number. That means all whole-number powers of that number, including negative powers. For instance, the cube of that number is $\frac{-117}{125}+\frac{44}{125}i$.

Comment: Because it is a multiplicative group,right? @Lubin. What did you mean by 'its dense there but not the whole circle group'?

Comment: Just that: it’s a subset of the topological space $S^1$ that’s dense therein. Since it’s countable while $S^1$ is uncountable, it’s not the whole set.

Comment: Thank you @Lubin,I understood that. How can i definitely conclude $S^{1}$ is a topological space?

Comment: Topological space? that’s easy: any subset has a topology coming from the big space. Signing off now — got too many things on my plate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Heine-Borel theorem, any subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it's bounded and closed.
Let $G$ be a compact subgroup of $\mathbb C^{\times}$, and assume $G$ has an element $x$ such that $|x|\neq 1$. We can assume $|x|<1$, instead we can use $x^{-1}$ to replace $x$. Then $x, x^2, x^3,\cdots$ is a sequence in $G$ that converges to 0, but $0 \notin G$, so $G$ is not compact.
Then $G \subseteq S^1$. Assume there is an element $Q=\exp(2\pi i q) \in G$ and $q$ is an irrational number, then for all $a \in [0,1]$, there is a sequence with elements in $G$ that converges to $A=\exp{2\pi i a} \in \mathbb C^{\times}$. We can prove it using rational approximation.
Let $q_n$ be an integer sequence such that $\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow\infty}\frac{q_p}{p}=Q$ where $p$ run through the sequence of prime numbers, and $\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_p}{p}=A$. Then $\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow\infty}x^{a_p \cdot (q_p^{-1} \mod p)}=a$.
So if there is such an ``irrational" element then the group is equal to $S^1$; if there is not the group is $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: I am confused about the statements from "Assume there is an element $Q= exp(2\pi i q)$ to nearly the end. If q is irrational - then, for all $a \in [0,1] $ therej is a sequence that converges to $exp(2 \pi i a)$. why? why are you considering the interval [0,1]? what did you mean by rational approximation. The last two sentences wasn't understood - about sequences divided by prime number - what are you trying to prove there?